# Currently I am facing challenge in sending proactive 1 to 1 messages to a large number of users in parallel without delay

Tags: node.js, microsoft-graph-api, botframework, microsoft-teams

Solution illustration:
[image]

Currently, i am facing challenge in sending proactive 1 to 1 messages to a large number of users in parallel without delay.

Right now I am trying these approaches:

For an array of conversationID’s  we use .map() to call our async/await function that sends a proactive messages, then Promise.all() to gather them back up again.
I am also trying to create workers using cluster module and distributing split of conversationid’s to each worker.

What is the recommended approach to overcome this issue?

Can I improve the solution by integrating with Microsoft graph API?

```
// Listen for incoming notifications and send proactive messages to users.
server.get('/api/notify', async (req, res) => {
    // map through the agents list
   
    const promises = userslist.map(async agent => {
        var sendmsg = sendUserMessage(user.conversationid);
         return sendmsg;   
   })
   
    const results = await Promise.all(promises)
    console.log(results);
    res.json(results);
    res.end();

});

// function to send message
const sendUserMessage = async function (userConversationReference) {
    try{
        
    MicrosoftAppCredentials.trustServiceUrl(serviceUrl);

    var credentials = new MicrosoftAppCredentials(process.env.BotId, process.env.BotPassword);
    var connectorClient = new ConnectorClient(credentials, { baseUri: serviceUrl });

    var message = MessageFactory.text("Hello this is a test notification!");
    // User Scope
    const conversationParameters = {
        isGroup: false,
        channelData: {
            tenant: {
                id: process.env.TENANT_ID
            }
        },
        bot: {
            id: process.env.BotId,
            name: process.env.BotName
        },
        members: [
            {
               id: userConversationReference    
            }
        ]
    };
    
    var conversationResponse = await connectorClient.conversations.createConversation(conversationParameters);
    var response = await connectorClient.conversations.sendToConversation(conversationResponse.id, message); 
    
    
    return response;
     } catch (error) {
    return error.statusCode;
    console.error(error);
  }
  


}
```

Comment: Could you please check this [sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/main/samples/javascript_nodejs/16.proactive-messages/bots/proactiveBot.js)?try if that helps.

Comment: In your question you write, *Currently, i am facing challenge in sending proactive 1 to 1 messages to a large number of users in parallel without delay.* and *What is the recommended approach to overcome this issue?* -- but you don't specify the problem you are encountering.  Might you please [edit] your question to clarify what the "challenge" is to overcome?

Comment: @Abhi are still facing issue? - Could you please conform?

Answer (score 0):

Here is documentation on how to [Optimize your bot with rate limiting in Teams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/rate-limit).

Sharing code snippet from the doc for your reference:

```
try
{
    // Perform Bot Framework operation
    // for example, await connector.Conversations.UpdateActivityAsync(reply);
}
catch (HttpOperationException ex)
{
    if (ex.Response != null && (uint)ex.Response.StatusCode ==  429)
    {
        //Perform retry of the above operation/Action method
    }
}
```

*Sample code references:*

[Teams Proactive Messaging Samples](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/tree/main/samples/bot-proactive-messaging/csharp)

[Company Communicator App Template](https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-apps-company-communicator/blob/master/Source/CompanyCommunicator.Common/Services/Teams/Messages/MessageService.cs#L85)